# PHP RegEx Matching Partial Data

Tags: php, regex

I am trying parse the ESPN bottom line feed using RegEx but am coming up a bit short. Instead of it getting all of the NFL games it is only getting about half.

This is the data returned by ESPN.

```
 &nfl_s_delay=120&nfl_s_stamp=0909064837&nfl_s_left1=^Dallas 24   NY Giants 17 (FINAL)&nfl_s_right1_count=0&nfl_s_url1=http://sports.espn.go.com/nfl/boxscore?gameId=320905019&nfl_s_left2=Indianapolis at Chicago (1:00 PM ET)&nfl_s_right2_count=0&nfl_s_url2=http://sports.espn.go.com/nfl/preview?gameId=320909003&nfl_s_left3=Philadelphia at Cleveland (1:00 PM ET)&nfl_s_right3_count=0&nfl_s_url3=http://sports.espn.go.com/nfl/preview?gameId=320909005&nfl_s_left4=St. Louis at Detroit (1:00 PM ET)&nfl_s_right4_count=0&nfl_s_url4=http://sports.espn.go.com/nfl/preview?gameId=320909008&nfl_s_left5=New England at Tennessee (1:00 PM ET)&nfl_s_right5_count=0&nfl_s_url5=http://sports.espn.go.com/nfl/preview?gameId=320909010&nfl_s_left6=Atlanta at Kansas City (1:00 PM ET)&nfl_s_right6_count=0&nfl_s_url6=http://sports.espn.go.com/nfl/preview?gameId=320909012&nfl_s_left7=Jacksonville at Minnesota (1:00 PM ET)&nfl_s_right7_count=0&nfl_s_url7=http://sports.espn.go.com/nfl/preview?gameId=320909016&nfl_s_left8=Washington at New Orleans (1:00 PM ET)&nfl_s_right8_count=0&nfl_s_url8=http://sports.espn.go.com/nfl/preview?gameId=320909018&nfl_s_left9=Buffalo at NY Jets (1:00 PM ET)&nfl_s_right9_count=0&nfl_s_url9=http://sports.espn.go.com/nfl/preview?gameId=320909020&nfl_s_left10=Miami at Houston (1:00 PM ET)&nfl_s_right10_count=0&nfl_s_url10=http://sports.espn.go.com/nfl/preview?gameId=320909034&nfl_s_left11=San Francisco at Green Bay (4:25 PM ET)&nfl_s_right11_count=0&nfl_s_url11=http://sports.espn.go.com/nfl/preview?gameId=320909009&nfl_s_left12=Seattle at Arizona (4:25 PM ET)&nfl_s_right12_count=0&nfl_s_url12=http://sports.espn.go.com/nfl/preview?gameId=320909022&nfl_s_left13=Carolina at Tampa Bay (4:25 PM ET)&nfl_s_right13_count=0&nfl_s_url13=http://sports.espn.go.com/nfl/preview?gameId=320909027&nfl_s_left14=Pittsburgh at Denver (8:20 PM ET)&nfl_s_right14_count=0&nfl_s_url14=http://sports.espn.go.com/nfl/preview?gameId=320909007&nfl_s_left15=Cincinnati at Baltimore (7:00 PM ET)&nfl_s_right15_count=0&nfl_s_url15=http://sports.espn.go.com/nfl/preview?gameId=320910033&nfl_s_left16=San Diego at Oakland (10:15 PM ET)&nfl_s_right16_count=0&nfl_s_url16=http://sports.espn.go.com/nfl/preview?gameId=320910013&nfl_s_count=16&nfl_s_loaded=true
```

I am using two RegEx patterns, one to catch games that are completed/in progress:

```
preg_match_all('/nfl_s_left\d{1,2}=\^?(?P<awayteam>[a-zA-Z]+(?:\s+[a-zA-Z]+)*)\s+(?P<awayscore>\d+)\s+\^?(?P<hometeam>[a-zA-Z]+(?:\s+[a-zA-Z]+)*)\s+(?P<homescore>\d+)\s+(?P<time>\(.*?\))/', $content, $matches_in_progress, PREG_SET_ORDER);
```

And another to catch games that haven't started yet:

```
preg_match_all('/nhl_s_left\d=\^?(?P<awayteam>[a-zA-Z]+(?:\s+[a-zA-Z]+)*)\s+(at)+\s+\^?(?P<hometeam>[a-zA-Z]+(?:\s+[a-zA-Z]+)*)\s(?P<time>\(.*?\))/', $content, $matches_upcoming, PREG_SET_ORDER);
```

Only 8 of the 16 games match, and I can't figure out why. The matches for this week are `Dallas at NY Giants`, `Philadelphia at Cleveland`, `New England at Tennessee`, `Atlanta at Kansas City`, `Jacksonville at Minnesota`, `Washington at New Orleans`, and `Buffalo at NY Jets`.

I'd very much appreciate any help getting my RegEx to match all 16 games for this week and weeks to come.

Edit: Modified string to match, forgot that I strip %20 before applying RegEx to it.

Comment: I cannot match anything with your regex because `%20` is not a whitespace. Can you provide real string that you use in your regex processing, string where HTML characters are removed?

Comment: @NikolaMalešević Sorry about that, I have edited my original post with the correct string, I forgot that I removed all the `%20` before applying my RegEx statement to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the error. I did not have `d{1,2}` in the 2nd regex to match games 10-16. And I also didn't have `+(?:\.*)` which forced St. Louis to be skipped over.

My new, working RegEx is:

```
/nfl_s_left\d{1,2}=\^?(?P<awayteam>[a-zA-Z]+(?:\.*)+(?:\s+[a-zA-Z]+)*)\s+(at)+\s+\^?(?P<hometeam>[a-zA-Z]+(?:\s+[a-zA-Z]+)*)\s(?P<time>\(.*?\))/
```

Answer (score 0):

Your regular expressions are very complicated. Since the original string is encoded as URL arguments, you could use `parse_str` to get a key => value array. Then use regular expressions to find the entries you want.

```
$string = "&nfl_s_delay=120&nfl_s_stamp=0909054449&nfl_s_left1=^Dallas%2024%20%20%20NY%20Giants%2017%20(FINAL)&nfl_s_right1_count=0&nfl_s_url1=http://sports.espn.go.com/nfl/boxscore?gameId=320905019&nfl_s_left2=Indianapolis%20at%20Chicago%20(1:00%20PM%20ET)&nfl_s_right2_count=0&nfl_s_url2=http://sports.espn.go.com/nfl/preview?gameId=320909003&nfl_s_left3=Philadelphia%20at%20Cleveland%20(1:00%20PM%20ET)&nfl_s_right3_count=0&nfl_s_url3=http://sports.espn.go.com/nfl/preview?gameId=320909005&nfl_s_left4=St.%20Louis%20at%20Detroit%20(1:00%20PM%20ET)&nfl_s_right4_count=0&nfl_s_url4=http://sports.espn.go.com/nfl/preview?gameId=320909008&nfl_s_left5=New%20England%20at%20Tennessee%20(1:00%20PM%20ET)&nfl_s_right5_count=0&nfl_s_url5=http://sports.espn.go.com/nfl/preview?gameId=320909010&nfl_s_left6=Atlanta%20at%20Kansas%20City%20(1:00%20PM%20ET)&nfl_s_right6_count=0&nfl_s_url6=http://sports.espn.go.com/nfl/preview?gameId=320909012&nfl_s_left7=Jacksonville%20at%20Minnesota%20(1:00%20PM%20ET)&nfl_s_right7_count=0&nfl_s_url7=http://sports.espn.go.com/nfl/preview?gameId=320909016&nfl_s_left8=Washington%20at%20New%20Orleans%20(1:00%20PM%20ET)&nfl_s_right8_count=0&nfl_s_url8=http://sports.espn.go.com/nfl/preview?gameId=320909018&nfl_s_left9=Buffalo%20at%20NY%20Jets%20(1:00%20PM%20ET)&nfl_s_right9_count=0&nfl_s_url9=http://sports.espn.go.com/nfl/preview?gameId=320909020&nfl_s_left10=Miami%20at%20Houston%20(1:00%20PM%20ET)&nfl_s_right10_count=0&nfl_s_url10=http://sports.espn.go.com/nfl/preview?gameId=320909034&nfl_s_left11=San%20Francisco%20at%20Green%20Bay%20(4:25%20PM%20ET)&nfl_s_right11_count=0&nfl_s_url11=http://sports.espn.go.com/nfl/preview?gameId=320909009&nfl_s_left12=Seattle%20at%20Arizona%20(4:25%20PM%20ET)&nfl_s_right12_count=0&nfl_s_url12=http://sports.espn.go.com/nfl/preview?gameId=320909022&nfl_s_left13=Carolina%20at%20Tampa%20Bay%20(4:25%20PM%20ET)&nfl_s_right13_count=0&nfl_s_url13=http://sports.espn.go.com/nfl/preview?gameId=320909027&nfl_s_left14=Pittsburgh%20at%20Denver%20(8:20%20PM%20ET)&nfl_s_right14_count=0&nfl_s_url14=http://sports.espn.go.com/nfl/preview?gameId=320909007&nfl_s_left15=Cincinnati%20at%20Baltimore%20(7:00%20PM%20ET)&nfl_s_right15_count=0&nfl_s_url15=http://sports.espn.go.com/nfl/preview?gameId=320910033&nfl_s_left16=San%20Diego%20at%20Oakland%20(10:15%20PM%20ET)&nfl_s_right16_count=0&nfl_s_url16=http://sports.espn.go.com/nfl/preview?gameId=320910013&nfl_s_count=16&nfl_s_loaded=true";
parse_str($string, $array);
var_dump($array);
```